# Volume bounds of balls in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and suppose $\mathrm{Ric}(g) \geq -k$ for some $k>0$.  Suppose we know that $\mathrm{vol}_g (B_1^g (x_0)) \geq \nu$ for some particular $x_0 \in M$ and some $\nu >0$.  Does this information tell us anything about a lower bound on $\mathrm{vol}_g (B_1^g (x))$ for other $x \in M$?

Comment: Bishop-Gromov volume comparison gives a bound in terms of $d(x,x_0)$ and $\nu$, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality

Answer (score 3):

No, for cusped hyperbolic manifolds you can have arbirtrarily small volumes of unitary balls.

In general also if $M$ is compact you can have very large balls and very thin margulis tubes.